# PHP код падает при присвоении значения элементу второго уровня многомерного массива

Tags: php, php8

Столкнулся со странной проблемой.

Имеется следующий "легаси" код:

```
$array['a']['b'] = 'val';
```

То есть значение присваивается сразу элементу второго уровня, без инициализации первого.

Код выполняется без проблем на всех серверах, кроме одного, на котором он падает без каких-либо ошибок и записей в лог. Не могу понять в чём может быть причина.

Конфигурация проблемного сервера:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Apache 2.4
- Nginx 1.19
- PHP 8.0

Локально конфигурация идентичная, но код работает. Тестировал так же на других серверах с различными версиями php, проблем не было.

Заранее спасибо.

P.S.: Я понимаю что проблема решается элементарно инициализацией первого уровня, просто интересна причина подобного поведения.

Answer (score 1):

Если взять данный код `$array['a']['b'] = 'val';` и [запустить](https://3v4l.org/dOS8A), то как видишь - ни в одной из поддерживаемых версий php не падает ни предупреждений, ни ошибок.

Теперь модифицируем код следующим образом:

```
$array['a'] = '42';
$array['a']['b'] = 'val';
```

[Запускаем](https://3v4l.org/VpWoM)

И видим, что в восьмых версиях падает **FatalError**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

Таким образом приходим к выводу, что где-то ранее в коде `$array['a']` инициализируется каким-то значением, отличным от массива.

Это поведение описано здесь: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.other, группа "A number of warnings have been converted into `Error` exceptions".

И да, чтобы ошибка записывалась в лог - должна быть выставлена соответствующая настройка (`log_errors`), ну `error_reporting` должна всегда иметь значение `E_ALL`.

Comment: Хорошая теория, спасибо, но, к сожалению, неверная. Подобный код(с $array['a'] = '42';) будет некорректно выполняться на любой версии php. В моём случае проблема наблюдается только на одном сервере, остальные же обрабатывают код корректно, в том числе и локальный с идентичной конфигурацией. Да, и error_reporting настроен.

Comment: Да, но в отличие от восьмерки, код с `$array['a'] = '42';` будет выбрасывать только варнинг. И если ты не видишь ни варнингов, ни ерроров - то `error_reporting` настроен как-то не так как надо.

Comment: да вроде бы всё правильно настроено, я даже display_errors включил в php.ini, но ошибок никаких, ни в выводе, ни в логе, просто молча падает. Ладно, буду считать это необъяснимой аномалией.